# Convert a regular autocomplete field into an autocomplete deluxe field?

Tags: 7, forms

I am using the following code.

```
   $form['usershare'] = array(
     '#title' => t('Share Collection Internally - Example: Alice, Bob, Pat'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#default_value' => empty($flag->usershare) ? '' : $flag->usershare,
     '#autocomplete_path' => 'user/autocomplete/fl',
     '#multiple' => TRUE,
   );
```

I installed the [Autocomplete Deluxe](https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) module.

How do I convert the code I am using to have a form field that uses autocomplete deluxe?

I tried changing the form field type to *autocomplete_deluxe*, but that didn't work as only a blank input box shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [README.txt](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/autocomplete_deluxe/tree/README.txt) file, something like this should work

> ```
>    $form['field_term_ref_tid'] = array(
>      '#type' => 'autocomplete_deluxe',
>      '#autocomplete_deluxe_path' => url(
>        'autocomplete_deluxe/taxonomy/field_term_ref',
>        array('absolute' => TRUE)
>      ),
>      '#multiple' => TRUE,
>      '#autocomplete_min_length' => 0,
>      '#autocomplete_multiple_delimiter' => ',',
>      '#not_found_message' => "The term '@term' will be added.",
>    );
> ```